# Cropping larger images to multiple sizes in node.js

Tags: node.js, image, express, amazon-s3

I am creating an image uploading system (size usually >20MB<50MB) and i want to crop that images to various sizes (its for viewing mobile,web and desktop application),all images are stored into AWS s3.

Here is the snapshot of crop-sizes

```
[{
 width:200,
 height:200,
 type:"small",
 platform:"web"},
{
 width:300,
 height:400,
 type:"small",
 platform:"mobile-android"
}
....
....
 ]
```

Here is the think i am planned to do

1.First upload the image into S3.

2.Run all the crop operations in async task

```
upload:function(req,res){

    //various cropsizes
    var cropSizes = [];
    //upload image to s3
    uploadImageToS3(req.file,function(err,result){
        if(!err){
            //create crop
            cropImage({
                'cropsizes':cropSizes,
                'file':req.file
            },function(err,result){
                console.log('all crop completed',result);
            });

            res.send('run crop in backgroud');
        }
    });

}
```

But is this correct method?? can anyone have better thing other than this???

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using s3 I would recommend trying aws lambda to resize your images and adding them back to s3 bucket with new sizes. 
Here is detailed explanation in this  link https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/resize-images-on-the-fly-with-amazon-s3-aws-lambda-and-amazon-api-gateway/

Comment: I have tried but sometimes AWS lambda is timeout out(in case of larger images)

Comment: How big is the images, I have tried larger images and it has worked flawlessly, Try increasing memory limit or Timout from console.

Comment: Image size greater than 20MB

Comment: 20 MB is not that big, lambda should be able to easily handle it. try some config changes. I guess there is some bottleneck in your code or somewhere that is triggering timeout.

Comment: Minimum image size is 20 mb at most is 50 mb

Comment: From My experience 50 mb size of image should be easily handled by lambda, default memory is 128 mb i guess which you can increase as well if needed and what module are you using to resize image?

Comment: I am using GM module

Comment: also from your question it seems like you are running in to timeout issues and not memory issue. Try looking in to your codebase if you have missing callback or you can also try increasing timeout to max to just check once.